# Variable in column

Tags: workflow-variable

I want to ask if it's this possible to do:
I have list with column and in this column this value:
ID: [%Actual_ID%]
Name: [%Name%]

And then I want using workflow to send email with this text, but I need to set actual ID and name, etc. of item from other list, which started WF. So basically in one list I want to have email pattern, which is used in other list WF and filled with actual values.

Comment: It depends, between these two lists, what two fields do the items share?  Do the elements have the same unique name?  Do they have the same ID?

Comment: Ok, let's say I have this two table see [link](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2ps36ew.jpg). And if item in table test is changed, WF starts. The WF looks in state column. Let's say the first item in table test was changed and in state column is 1. The WF looks in table email_pattern and find item with state_id 1 and sends email by this pattern. So email is send to adress example@test.com with subject subject1 and text Hello, field1: field1_1 field2: field2_1. I hope it's understandable now.

Comment: Alright, last question before I have my answer.  What version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2010

Comment: So, do you have your answer now? :D

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry, forgot to answer, haha.  As far as I know, there is no way to address looking up another field with it's own lookups.  My best bet would to just use if cases to style your email addresses, based on status, rather than having a seperate list to have that.  That is, assuming you don't have many statuses.

Comment: Thought, if it is only your subjects differing, you can definitely do a lookup on that.  As long as there are no lookups in the field you are attempting to lookup, it should be fine.

Comment: My originally idea was having email patterns in one table (about 20 or more), so responsible user can change it as he wants (like Hello, your email has id: [%id], etc.). But I need those information from the first table and that's the problem.